# Return string read from buffer and function without dynamic allocation?

Tags: c++, string, pointers

How would I go about returning a string built from a buffer within a function without dynamically allocating memory?

Currently I have this function to consider:

```
    // Reads null-terminated string from buffer in instance of buffer class.
    // uint16 :: unsigned short
    // ubyte :: unsigned char
    ubyte* Readstr( void ) {
        ubyte* Result = new ubyte[]();

        for( uint16 i = 0; i < ByteSize; i ++ ) {
            Result[ i ] = Buffer[ ByteIndex ];
            ByteIndex ++;

            if ( Buffer[ ByteIndex - 1 ] == ubyte( 0 ) ) {
                ByteIndex ++;
                break;
            };
        };

        return Result;
    };
```

While I can return the built string, I can't do this without dynamic allocation. This becomes a problem if you consider the following usage:

```
// Instance of buffer class "Buffer" calling Readstr():
    cout << Buffer.Readstr() << endl;
    // or...
    ubyte String[] = Buffer.String();
```

Usages similar to this call result in the same memory leak as the data is not being deleted via `delete`. I don't think there is a way around this, but I am not entirely sure if it's possible.

Comment: I don't know what you're expecting out of `new ubyte[]()`, but it's [not legal C++](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/3f70e4001c312178).

Comment: Why not use `std::vector<ubyte>`?  Or `basic_string<ubyte>`?

Comment: Is use of `std::string` prohibited?

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie You mean with a non-dynamic allocator?

Comment: I suggest returning an unnamed temporary once you've built the string you want and then rely on RVO. Probably not the most standard way though, I'd like to know if there's something better..

Comment: @chris, it is legal C++. It's simply creating a new unsigned character array. @40two No. However, I'd like to know how to approach the situation without the use of `string`.

Comment: @user3519915, For that to work, it needs to know the size of what's being allocated. What do you propose that is? Evidently not 0 since you're indexing it. Arrays in C++ work a lot differently from Java or C#.

Comment: @user3519915 - `I'd like to know how to approach the situation without the use of string`  Write your own RAII string class.

Comment: @juanchopanza - Using the default allocator.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie I thought that uses dynamic allocation, which apparently must be avoided.

Comment: @juanchopanza - Depends on what the OP means by "no dynamic allocation".  Don't know whether that means none whatsoever, or no dynamic allocation explicitly done by the user code (but hidden behind the scenes).

Comment: With dynamic allocation such as using `new` forces the user to delete the dynamically allocated string with `delete`. If they don't then you get a memory leak. This is the biggest issue.

Comment: @user3519915 - Then hide those details from the user.  That's what RAII is all about.  How does `std::string` work without the user calling `new` and `delete`?  Surely `std::string` may allocate memory, no?

Comment: It will allocate memory, but I don't think it'd result in a memory leak as using `new` would. Correct? If so `string` would be ideal. I don't mind allocating memory as long as it doesn't force the user to delete it or result in a memory leak.

Comment: @user3519915, Correct, `std::string` handles all that for you.

Comment: That would work then. I stayed away from `string` originally because I didn't know it did this.

Comment: @user3519915 - std::string will more than likely use `new` internally. The difference is that it knows (via user-defined copy constructor, assignment operator, destructor) when and how to call `delete`, how to copy itself to another string, etc.  If you really didn't want to use `std::string`, then this is why I suggested writing a class that does what `std::string` does in terms of memory management.  Problem is that you would then need to learn how to do this, and that in itself is another kettle of fish.

Comment: Yeah, I'd rather just use `std::string` for simplicity.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are at least three ways you could reimplement the method to avoid a direct allocation with `new`.

### The Good:

Use a `std::vector` (This will allocate heap memory):

```
std::vector<ubyte> Readstr() 
{
    std::vector<ubyte> Result;
    for (uint16 i = 0; i < ByteSize; i++) 
    {
        Result.push_back(Buffer[ByteIndex]);
        ByteIndex++;

        if (Buffer[ByteIndex - 1] == ubyte(0)) 
        {
            ByteIndex++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return Result;
}
```

### The Bad:

Force the caller to provide an output buffer and possibly a size do avoid overflows (Does not directly allocate memory):

```
ubyte* Readstr(ubyte* outputBuffer, size_t maxCount) 
{
    for (uint16 i = 0; i < ByteSize; i++) 
    {
        if (i == maxCount)
            break;

        outputBuffer[i] = Buffer[ByteIndex];
        ByteIndex++;

        if (Buffer[ByteIndex - 1] == ubyte(0)) 
        {
            ByteIndex++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return outputBuffer;
}
```

### The Ugly:

Use an internal static array and return a reference to it:

```
ubyte* Readstr() 
{
    enum { MAX_SIZE = 2048 }; // Up to you to decide the max size...
    static ubyte outputBuffer[MAX_SIZE];

    for (uint16 i = 0; i < ByteSize; i++) 
    {
        if (i == MAX_SIZE)
            break;

        outputBuffer[i] = Buffer[ByteIndex];
        ByteIndex++;

        if (Buffer[ByteIndex - 1] == ubyte(0)) 
        {
            ByteIndex++;
            break;
        }
    }
    return outputBuffer;
}
```

Be aware that this last option has several limitations, including possibility of data races in multithreaded application and inability to call it inside a recursive function, among other subtle issues. But otherwise, is probably the closest to what you are looking for and can be used safely if you take some precautions and make some assumptions about the calling code.

Answer (score 5):

Personally, I'd recommend just return `std::string` or `std::vector<T>`: this neatly avoids memory leaks and the string won't allocate memory for small strings (well, most implementations are going that way but not all are quite there).

The alternative is to create a class which can hold a big enough array and return an object that type:

```
struct buffer {
     enum { maxsize = 16 };
     ubyte buffer[maxsize];
};
```

If you want get more fancy and support bigger strings which would then just allocate memory you'll need to deal a bit more with constructors, destructors, etc. (or just use `std::vector<ubyte>` and get over it).

Comment: Now I'm curious. Are there any implementations in particular that don't have SSO?

Comment: @chris: sure. libstc++ for example: they still use a COW string! They have implemented a SSO string but the change to make it `std::basic_string` will happen when they move to full C++11 conformance, breaking the ABI (not of the core language features but of the library) at this point.

Comment: Interesting, thanks. I thought the COW strings had been wiped out, at least in MSVC/GCC/Clang.

Comment: @chris: COW is prohibited by C++11. There were fights trying to keep it (based on arguments about ABI stability) but the perils of data races would have prevented reasonable uses even for non-COW strings to make COW work reasonable and the fight was finally won!

Comment: Well, I did hear about COW strings becoming prohibited, although I never looked too much into why. Perhaps I should learn a bit more about the ABI, especially considering C++11 made breaking changes to it.